# Show that Pythogoras' theorem is fulfilled for a triple of vectors with respect to inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a_i > 0$ for $1 \le i \le n$.

$\langle (x_1, \ldots, x_n)^T, (y_1, \ldots, y_n)^T \rangle = a_1 x_1 y_1 + \ldots + a_n x_n y_n$ define an inner product on $\mathbb R^n$. (I've verified that.)

Set $a_i = i$ and $n=3$.

Compute the vectorprojection $p$ of $u=(0,1,0)^T$ on $v=(0,1,1)^T$ with respect to the inner product above.

I've computed $p = \frac {\langle u,v \rangle} {\langle v,v \rangle} v= \frac 2 5 v = \frac 2 5 (0,1,1)^T$

Compute $||u||=\sqrt 2, ||p|| = \sqrt {\frac 4 5}, || u-p|| = \sqrt {\frac {14} 5}$ (I've done this).

**Now I must show that Pythogoras' theorem is fulfilled for this triple of vectors ?**

Could someone clarify what this means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard inner product, if $p$ is the projection of $u$ on $v$, then  $p$ and $u-p$ are orthogonal, and Pythagoras's theorem gives $||u||^2 = ||p||^2 + ||u-p||^2$.

The question is asking you to show that this is still true with the non-standard inner product. But you can't do this, because your calculation of $||u-p||$ is wrong!

Comment: Thanks, @TonyK. This was just what I needed. I've found out that $||u-p||$ was wrongly calculated and the result is actually $\sqrt {\frac 6 5}$

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that you have to prove that $$||x+y||^2 = ||x||^2+||y||^2,$$
since this is what the Pythagoras' theorem states for $2$ orthogonal planar vectors.

Since $$||x+y||^2 = \langle x+y, x+y\rangle = ||x||^2 + \langle x,y\rangle + \langle y,x\rangle + ||y||^2,$$
the equation should not be hard to prove.

Comment: In my case what is $x$ and $y$ ? I've 3 vectors namely $u, p$ and $u-p$ ?